# Android scale and transition in parallel

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I got problem with my onclick animation, see here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zX7RkzCFlI4
I've got three elements in my layout, it is: wrapper, blue circle and star. Every element has own animation:

```
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.heart_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_logo);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView logo = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.heart);
    logo.clearAnimation();
    logo.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_circle);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.heart_circle);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

    final FrameLayout fr = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.heart_frame);
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_frame);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.heart_frame).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    anim.reset();
    fr.clearAnimation();
    fr.startAnimation(anim);
```

in translate_frame I got:

```
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="40%p" android:toYDelta="50%p"
    android:duration="950"
    android:startOffset="700"/>

<scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.5" android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:startOffset="700"
    android:pivotX="1"
    android:pivotY="1"
    android:duration="290" android:fillBefore="false" />
```

Every think seems good for me so why it not work propertry? Do you have any ide how to run it?

It should goes to bottom right corner with scale to 0.5

Comment: Your video is private, can't see it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now is online

Comment: So it looks like it is animating to its parent values, ie the element. The circle is inside a framelayout? that looks like it is an element in a listview? The circle doesn't consider what is outside of its element, I think there might be a way, but you will need to research about drawing outside of bounds.